# Unable to install catkin, Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ros2, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to follow the installation guide to make a catkin ws but then it said i needed to install it first.
Then i tried to install it but i got this error. https://imgur.com/a/M7GkE2T

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/407142/unable-to-install-catkin,-ubuntu-22.04/) by [swqtt](https://answers.ros.org/users/119493/swqtt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-09-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2022-09-29**:
Please don't use screenshots, copy the raw text so it's searchable and highlightable.

ALso please provide more context as to how your system is setup and what you've done before getting to the current command. As it stands there's a lot of guesses that can be made and you are likely mixing [Upstream Packages](http://wiki.ros.org/UpstreamPackages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS1 uses `catkin`, not ROS2 - which tutorial are you trying to follow?

In Ubuntu 22.04 you have to use upstream packages to have ROS1 Noetic installed:

- https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/How-To-Guides/Using-ros1_bridge-Jammy-upstream.html

For ROS2 Humble you should use `colcon` to build packages in your `ros2_ws`/`dev_ws`/...

- [Official `colcon` workspace tutorial](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Colcon-Tutorial.html#create-a-workspace)

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-09-30**:
@ljaniec: could we please always make it *very* clear the *upstream packages* you refer to are *not* the same packages hosted by `packages.ros.org`, but packages maintained, built and distributed by a 3rd party?

I notice people starting to "recommend" using those when users ask "how to install Noetic on Jammy?". In a way, that's ok, but there are subtle differences between those packages and the official Noetic binary packages which could lead to them running into "strange things" later (the upstream packages wiki page has a few good examples).

Using those packages is ok if you have a bit of experience, but for newcomers, which the OP appears to be, I'm not sure recommending their use is a good idea -- at least not without a warning.

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-09-30**:
@gvdhoorn Thank you for your comment, you are right. This will be a potential source of errors in the future. I will always add this information and perhaps recommend other approaches that would be more suitable for OP needs.